# Add constraints programmatically on FBLikeControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

How can I add constraints programmatically on a view like `FBLikeControl` ?

I would like to add just right margin to my `CGRect` to my view : `self.view` with `FBLikeControl` inside.

Here is my code :

```
FBLikeControl *fbLikeControlView = [[FBLikeControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 20, 165, 30)];
fbLikeControlView.likeControlStyle = FBLikeControlStyleBoxCount;
[self.view addSubview:fbLikeControlView];
//    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:fbLikeControlView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:nil
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:20.0];
```

I've tested one NSLayoutConstraint with attribute `attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight` that doesn't crash but if I write `NSLayoutAttributeRightMargin` that crash...

I don't know how to make that, and I don't find a good tutorial :/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using auto layout to place the FBLikeControl, you need to add enough constraints to place it unambiguously. You are just adding a height constraint. You need to also add horizontal constraints and a vertical offset constraint.

Also you need to call `[fbLikeControlView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]`

If you could give more details about how you want to layout it, I could help you with the constraints.